# Magento how to sync orders another mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a Magento store and when products are purchased the ordered data is inserted into the Magento Database and another application database.

Sometimes that data doesn't make it to the other application database for reasons we are not aware of and we can't figure out why at this time.

My question is, is it possible to keep that "ordered" data in sync with the other database?  I'm saying a one-way sync every 15 mins or so.  Like writing a script or another way to fire the data to the other database?

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Anurag has pointed out, you could use `sales_order_place_after` or `sales_order_invoice_pay`.  However, this would put it into the pipeline of order placement, and that might be a bad thing if you've got connectivity issues, or something similar.

The fact that you don't know why data isn't making it into the other database is probably a primary concern, and you won't want customers potentially taking the burden of any errors.

My suggestion would be to build a module that you configure to run every 15 mins that fires data into your other database.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <namespace_orders>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>namespace_orders/orders::run</model>
            </run>
        </namespace_orders>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: you can use this solution with an flag like **sent_to_application** to your order ,
than after you just need to **filter** the collection with **sent_to_application** not eq to 'sent', and than implement a foreach loop of orders and make sure to set the flag to order **sent_to_application** to **sent** once you have the order info to your database.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a cron job to this, or you can hook [sales_order_place_after](http://www.codepetals.com/how-to-hook-a-magento-event/) event to push your data into another database.